# Ember.js 1.0rc6 - RSVP is not defined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I'm following the example on how to make an authenticated route here: https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589

However when I run this code:

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!authTokenPresent) { 
      return RSVP.reject();
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: RSVP is not defined
```

I'm pretty new to this whole promises thing, so I assumed this was something just baked into ember for rejecting a promise. Should I be doing something different here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm pretty new to this whole promises thing, so I assumed this was something just baked into ember for rejecting a promise. Should I be doing something different here?

Try `Ember.RSVP.reject`. The `RSVP` module is prefixed with the `Ember` namespace when used in ember, see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.html).

Hope it helps.